# How to fetch all the records in some column in interactive grid Oracle APEX (without using forEach)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex

How do I fetch all the records in some column in interactive grid in Oracle APEX (without using forEach)? For example, I have a grid with columns: first name, last name, age, etc... I want to fetch all the ages and check for duplicates using JavaScript or jQuery by using for (NOT forEach) loop...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let age = [];
let model = apex.region(<staticId>).widget().interactiveGrid('getViews').grid.model;
let totalRecords = model.getTotalRecords(true);
for (let index = 0; index < totalRecords; index++) 
{
  let record = model.recordAt(index);
  if (record)
  {
      age[index] = model.getValue(record, "AGE");
  }
}
```

Comment: The code works, however instead of the line `age[index] = model.getValue(record, "AGE");` , it should be `age[index] = record[<the column number in the record>];`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/23.2/aexjs/model.html#getValue

Comment: At first I tried like this, but it showed some error in the console...